# 1d array to 2d array in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I have

```
arr[0] = ['2020-11-28T17:00:00,ITA,33299,3762,37061,752247,789308,1415,26323,720861,54363,942048,622484,1564532,21637641,12842250,']
arr[1] = ['2020-11-29T17:00:00,ITA,32879,3753,36632,759139,795771,6463,20648,734503,54904,958832,626346,1585178,21814575,12922382,']
...
```

I should transform this 1d array into a 2d array like

```
arr[0][0] = ['2020-11-28T17:00:00']
arr[0][1] = ['ITA']
...
```

How can I do? I've been hitting my head since the afternoon but I just can't.
Thanks

Comment: how is your original array looking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `arr` is like:

```py
>>> arr = [['2020-11-28T17:00:00,ITA,33299,3762,37061,752247,789308,1415,26323,720861,54363,942048,622484,1564532,21637641,12842250,'], ['2020-11-29T17:00:00,ITA,32879,3753,36632,759139,795771,6463,20648,734503,54904,958832,626346,1585178,21814575,12922382,']]
>>>
>>> # so that:
>>> arr[0]
['2020-11-28T17:00:00,ITA,33299,3762,37061,752247,789308,1415,26323,720861,54363,942048,622484,1564532,21637641,12842250,']
>>> arr[1]
['2020-11-29T17:00:00,ITA,32879,3753,36632,759139,795771,6463,20648,734503,54904,958832,626346,1585178,21814575,12922382,']
```

You can use a list comprehension:

```py
>>> arr = [[[x2] for x2 in x1[0].split(',')] for x1 in arr]
>>>
>>> # so now:
>>> arr[0][0]
['2020-11-28T17:00:00']
>>> arr[0][1]
['ITA']
```

Comment: Thank you! Very nice

Answer (score 0):

You can use [split](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp) operation on each subarray and update the resulting array into the original one.

```
for i in range(len(arr)):
    newarray = arr[i][0].split(',') # Creating new list
    arr.pop(i) # Remove old list
    arr.insert(i, newarray) # Adding new list in same
```

This will produce following output for your given input

```
[['2020-11-28T17:00:00', 'ITA', '33299', '3762', '37061', '752247', '789308', '1415', '26323', '720861', '54363', '942048', '622484', '1564532', '21637641', '12842250', ''],
['2020-11-29T17:00:00', 'ITA', '32879', '3753', '36632', '759139', '795771', '6463', '20648', '734503', '54904', '958832', '626346', '1585178', '21814575', '12922382', '']]
```